# Opacity change in rendering

Tags: three.js, rendering, opacity

In my code I have defined a circle:

```
     var material1 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, opacity: contentionopacity} );
    scene.add(circle);

    var resolution1 = 100;
    var amplitude1 = 60;              
    var size1 = 360 / resolution1;

    geometry1 = new THREE.Geometry();

    for(var i = 0; i <= resolution1; i++) {
        var segment1 = ( i * size1 ) * Math.PI / 180;
        geometry1.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(
            new THREE.Vector3(
                (Math.cos(segment1) * amplitude1)  , 
                400, 
                (Math.sin(segment1) * amplitude1) -100 )
            )
        );         
    }


    feetcircle = new THREE.Line( geometry1, material1 );
    scene.add(feetcircle)
```

In there is the part where I defined the opacity with 'contentionopacity'.

The question is... Is it still possible that while it's being rendered, I can change it's opacity (and thus make it appear/dissapear with the 'push of a button'?:

'rendering part':

```
   if (circleX1 == undefined) circleX1 = (neckcoords[0][1] -100 )//( ((neckcoords[0][1])-305) * Math.cos(rad) - (neckcoords[0][2] * Math.sin(rad)) )  +330 ;
            if (circleY1 == undefined) circleY1 = (neckcoords[0][2] -530) //( neckcoords[0][2] * Math.cos(rad) + neckcoords[0][1] * Math.sin(rad) )  ;
           // if (circleZ1 == undefined) circleZ1 = ( neckcoords[0][0] -90)  ;


            for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                feetcircle.geometry.vertices[i].x +=  (neckcoords[0][1] - circleX1 ) //(neckcoords[0][1] * Math.cos(rad) - neckcoords[0][2] * Math.sin(rad))  - circleX ;
                feetcircle.geometry.vertices[i].z +=  ( neckcoords[0][2] - circleY1) //- ( neckcoords[0][2] * Math.cos(rad) + neckcoords[0][1] * Math.sin(rad) - circleY);
               //feetcircle.geometry.vertices[i].y +=  ( neckcoords[0][0] - circleZ1);
            }



            circleX1 = neckcoords[0][1] //* Math.cos(rad) - neckcoords[0][2] * Math.sin(rad) ;
            circleY1 = neckcoords[0][2] //* Math.cos(rad) + neckcoords[0][1] * Math.sin(rad);
            //circleZ1 = neckcoords[0][0] //* Math.cos(rad) + neckcoords[0][0] * Math.sin(rad);
            feetcircle.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

'push of the button':

```
    document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == '17') { contentionopacity=contentionopacity+0.1}

                    console.log(contentionopacity)
                },
                false)
   document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == '61') { contentionopacity=contentionopacity-0.1}

                    console.log(contentionopacity)
                },
                false)
```

At the moment, the console log shows that the 'contentionopacity' is getting higher, but it doesn't change the opacity of the circle at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code looks several years old. You need to upgrade to the current version. Yes, it is possible to change the opacity with a button.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Do you mean like:  Use THREE.Vector3 instead of THREE.vertex ? And how do you exactly changhe the opacity with just a button while rendering?

Comment: Yes. What version are you using? Search the net for how to program a button.